# Why don't my loop of incrementing pointer end but cut off and printing weird output?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to coding with pointers.
This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int* p = &a;

    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
        p++;
        *(p) = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << p << " " << *p << endl;
    }
}
```

Somehow, the code keeps ending before the loop end and print out a series of address but then in the last address end with 03. Can anyone help I search all over but nothing.
output:

```
00000073532FF808 2
00000073532FF80C 8
00000073532FF810 5
00000073532FF814 1
00000073532FF818 10
00000073532FF81C 5
00000073532FF820 9
00000073532FF824 9
0000007300000003
```

Comment: Why are you writingting to the memory area that you do not own?

Comment: `int a` provides storage for _one_ `int`, and `p` is initialized to point to this storage. Thus, incrementing `p` moves it to unallocated memory. Writing to `*p` afterwards is U.B. (I suspect that `i` might be modified by this as well.)

Comment: We need a cannonical question for "Why do strange things happen when I shoot my memory with a shotgun?"

Answer (score 1):

First, there is allocated storage for one `int`.

```
    int a = 1;
```

Second a pointer which points to this storage.

```
    int *p = &a;
```

Now, writing to `*p` will modify `a` but...

```
    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
        p++;
        *(p) = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

i.e. `p` is incremented.

Even in the first loop it now points to memory beyond `a`.

That memory is either allocated for something else, or used for something else, or not allocated at all.
In any case, this is [**Undefined Behavior**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) i.e. writing out of bounds.

That's the nature of Undefined Behavior that everything is possible now—no predictions can be made anymore what will happen.

If the loop terminates before 10 iterations are done I suspect that `i` might be corrupted by this. It's also possible that `p` corrupts itself. This doesn't change the fact that it's Undefined Behavior.

---

A possible fix of OPs application would be to provide sufficient storage in `a` where `p` can be iterated over without going out-of-bounds.

For this, the definitions at the beginning of `main()` had to be changed to:

```
    int a[11] = { 1 };
    int* p = a; // could also be: int* p = &a[0];
```

Please, note that `p` is incremented before writing to it.
Hence, in the last iteration (with `i` = 9), `p` will point to `a[10]` before the write access. Therefore, the minimal sufficient array size is `int a[11]` instead of `int a[10]` which someone might think from the first glance.

---

The fixed program of OP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[11] = { 1 };
    int* p = a;

    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
        p++;
        *(p) = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << p << " " << *p << endl;
    }
    // double check
    cout << "a:";
    for (int value : a) cout << ' ' << value;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7fff57151bc4 4
0x7fff57151bc8 7
0x7fff57151bcc 8
0x7fff57151bd0 6
0x7fff57151bd4 4
0x7fff57151bd8 6
0x7fff57151bdc 7
0x7fff57151be0 3
0x7fff57151be4 10
0x7fff57151be8 2
a: 1 4 7 8 6 4 6 7 3 10 2
```

[Live Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87bc89c3dcce9565)

Comment: okay. but then, I must ask how to (or if it's possible) assign values to address that are incremental to variable a?

Comment: @nup You have to ensure enough allocation. E.g. `int a[10] = { 1 }; int *p = a;`. This sets the `p` to the address of the (first element of the) array `a`. Now, you can iterate `p` 10 times before you point past the end of `a` -> no U.B. anymore.

Comment: @nup Btw. according to your specific logic you need an array `int a[11]`, as you increment `p` before writing to its contents. (That this is a post-fix increment doesn't change things as it becomes effective until "next sequence point" and `;` is such a sequence point.)